# How can I upgrade my iMac to Lion 10.7?

Tags: macos, imac

I have a late 2006 iMac which I would like to upgrade to mac os x  10.7. What options are available to me, such as download or DVD, and where can I buy it from? Will the seller deliver it to my location in Amman, Jordan?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific in your question? Please edit the question so that it is easier to understand what your main question is.

Answer (score 3):

OSX 10.7 Lion was not sold on DVD, the first retail OSX version to do so. You can obtain it through three methods:

1. Update your system to 10.6.8 (combo update is best via Apple, or Software Update if you like) and then, using the Mac App Store, purchase a copy of Lion
2. Purchase Lion via the Apple Store website which will email you a download redemption code for Lion: http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion
3. Use eBay or another website to purchase an official Lion USB key, released for those who cannot download the product. Check with the various sellers to see if they deliver to your location.